# Genymotion Emulator audio sounds much deeper than normal

Tags: android, audio, genymotion

I have a problem with my genymotion emulator on Mac OX Yosemite. I have tried several devices, but every time, the voice and sounds are very deep. I was wondering whether anyone who has used virtual box or genymotion knows how to fix this problem.